# Is there any big problem using mybatis code in vertx.executeBlocking code?

Tags: java, mybatis, vert.x

I want to use `MyBatis` to read and write database in Eclipse Vert.x. Vert.x officially recommends using `executeBlocking` to handle [blocking code](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#blocking_code).

Is there any big problem using MyBatis code in vertx.executeBlocking code? What needs attention？

In Vert.x, using vert.executeBlocking or Worker verticles to run a program that blocks jdbc code, the performance and concurrency will not be as good as that of a traditional blocking program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clarification: Vert.x states that if you *absolutely must* use blocking code, you could wrap it into "executeBlocking". This is definitely not a recommendation or a good practice to do so.

First, executeBlocking will run on a default worker thread pool, which is quite small for long running tasks - 20 threads, by default.
Second, if you invoke this from your EventLoop verticles (such as a Router, for example) your concurrency will be even worse due to thread affinity. Basically, this will result in having a blocking thread pool of size equal to number of your CPU cores.
If your application doesn't need to scale and doesn't need throughput - that may be fine. But then maybe Vert.x is not the best choice anyway.

Much more scalable way would be to run your DB code in a set of worker verticles, communicating with your handler using EventBus.

Comment: There is, just after `executeBlocking` part: https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#blocking_code

Comment: In Vert.x, using vert.executeBlocking or Worker verticles to run a program that blocks jdbc code, the performance and concurrency will not be as good as that of a traditional blocking program?

Comment: That depends on what "traditional blocking program" is. A lot of languages and frameworks compensate concurrency limitation by having bigger pool of threads. Vert.x doesn't do that.

Comment: such as Spring-MVC. Compare with vert.x-Web running blocking code?

Comment: Spring MVC is usually run on Tomcat, which has a default thread pool of 200 threads. Now compare that with having 4-8 threads in Vert.x